# Does SQL use both indexes for an AND clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose query is

```
select * 
from tbl 
where a = 10 and b = 50
```

There are 2 indexes; one for col `a` and one for col `b`.

Will SQL Server use both indexes?

Comment: Yes, most likely. Just run the query and look at the **actual execution plan** to see if SQL Server really does use both indexes (the query optimizer is still free to use an index- or not - depending on various factors)

Comment: Assuming both indexes are nonclustered, I would expect SQL Server to use only one of the indexes in the same query, the most selective one based on the literal values. The same query with different literal values might use the other index if it's more selective based on the values. If neither index is selective enough, the table/clustered index will be scanned instead. The most optimal index for this query would be a clustered composite key on both a and b or a nonclustered index on a and be that includes all columns.

Comment: This really depends on the SELECT statement and the corresponding statistics. As both indexes are non-covering, the outcome might be: Table Scan or Index Seeks including Key Lookups. But it's very hard to tell from just the statement. Best bet is to check the execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my (now deleted) comment, this totally depends on your data. Take this [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=40ad5240230a8d2e95d65895ab5059fa) example:

```
--Create identical sample tables
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                   ColA int,
                   ColB int,
                   ColC datetime2(7));

CREATE TABLE tbl2 (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                   ColA int,
                   ColB int,
                   ColC datetime2(7));

CREATE TABLE tbl3 (ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                   ColA int,
                   ColB int,
                   ColC datetime2(7));
GO
--Create identical sample indexes
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1A ON tbl1 (ColA);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_1B ON tbl1 (ColB);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_2A ON tbl2 (ColA);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_2B ON tbl2 (ColB);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_3A ON tbl3 (ColA);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_3B ON tbl3 (ColB);
GO
--Create 1 row where A is 10 and B is 50
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
INSERT INTO tbl1 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT I,
       I+40,
       SYSUTCDATETIME()
FROM Tally;
GO
--Create 10 rows where A is 10, but where only one of those B is 50
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
INSERT INTO tbl2 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT (I-1) / 10,
       I - 55,
       SYSUTCDATETIME()
FROM Tally;
GO
--Create 10 rows where A is 10 and B is 50
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4)
INSERT INTO tbl3 (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT (I/10),
       (I/10)+40,
       SYSUTCDATETIME()
FROM Tally;
```

Now let's perform your query above and look at the execution plans:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
WHERE ColA = 10
  AND ColB = 50;
```

[image: <code>tbl1</code> Query Plan]

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl2
WHERE ColA = 10
  AND ColB = 50;
```

[image: <code>tbl2</code> Query Plan]

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl3
WHERE ColA = 10
  AND ColB = 50;
```

[image: <code>tbl3</code> query plan]

As you can see, all 3 queries, which are identical, produced different query plans. For `tbl1` the use of the index against `ColA` or `ColB` would return 1 row so a seek could be performed on either and then a Key Lookup to check the value of the other and get the values of `ColC` (as it needs to be displayed). Therefore both were likely seen just as "cost effective", and so the data engine used `IX_1A`.

For the second query, it was quicker for the data engine to use `IX_2B` because it's more selective; there was only 1 row where `ColB` had a value of `50`, so a seek could be performed against that column. Then (again) a key lookup against was performed to check the value of the other column (and get the value of `ColC`). In this case it did have a value of `10`, so was returned.

Finally, in the last query, both were as selective again but there were multiple rows where `ColA` and `ColB` had values of `10` and `50` respectively. As a result the Data Engine performed a seek against both indexes, followed by a Merge Join for where the rows those values intersect (as the Primary key will be included in both indexes as it's clustered). Finally, again, it performs a Key lookup to get the value of `ColC`.

If we create a table without a `CLUSTERED INDEX` we get similar behaviour, apart from a heap lookup, and for the latter query a Hash Match:

[image]

*Edit: Incase the comments are removed, the above images show variables due to me using `SET STATISTICS XML ON;`, which appears to show a plan based on variables, not literals. Using `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;` shows the actual query instead. For the purposes of this test, at least, both `SHOWPLAN_XML` and `STATISTICS XML` provide the same query plans for each query.*

Comment: The query text in the Explain output looks to be local variables. Do you get the same result with literals?

Comment: They were literals when I ran the queries, @DanGuzman . I assume it's a feature of either the data engine or ADS, to replace those values with variables. You can see, for example, in a GitHub I raised (on a separate issue) that the query clearly has literals but in the Query Plan shows variables. [Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/8693).

Comment: Looks to be the database engine with `SET STATISTICS XML ON`. Interestingly, it doesn't happen with `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON`.

Comment: You're right, @DanGuzman . I do, however, get the same results for both `SET STATISTICS XML ON` and `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` (Query plan wise). Interesting thing to notice though.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no.  The optimal index for this query is on `(a, b)` or `(b, a)` -- the ordering of the keys in this case has little impact.

If you have separate indexes on `(a)` and `(b)`, then SQL Server is likely to choose the more selective index (i.e. the one with more key value).  It will then scan that index looking up the value of the other key.  You can see this if you look at the `explain` plan.

MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) actually has a reasonable introduction to the basic use of multi-column indexes.  There is functionality that MySQL does not implement, so it is not covered here ("skip-scan"s and "index merge" for `or` operations come to mind).